# DateFormat conversion

Tags: shell-script, date

Am trying to cut the three columns using awk command.

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 rouser users 33 Oct 19 05:20 b.sh
```

Am using this below line to cut the 33 Oct 19 05:20 values.

```
z=`ls -l b.sh | awk '{print $6,$7,$8 }'`
echo $z
```

z will give the result as 33 Oct 19 05:20 .

What my question is, I want date, month, year in this format 19/10/2016.
what should I do??
kindly help me as soon as possible.

Comment: On what system?

Comment: Similar: [Full file date (without GNU utilities)](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/255524)

Answer (score 2):

A few notes about parsing `ls` output:

- the format depends on the locale. If you need to parse it, you need to fix the locale to something known, typically `C`
- in the `ls -l` output, as the user name and group name appear before the date and may contain spaces (rare in practice though), you can't rely on the date being always on the 6th field. It's better to use `ls -n` to use numeric uid/gid instead (or `-o`, `-g` with implementations that have them).
- if the file is of type directory, `ls -l file` would list its content. You want the `-d` option (`LC_ALL=C ls -nd -- "$file"` so far).
- if the file name (or the target of the symlink for files of type symlink) contains newline characters, then you need to make sure you only consider the first line of the output

  ```
  LC_ALL=C ls -nd -- "$file" | awk '{print $6,$7,$8; exit}'
  ```
- In the C locale, the format of the modification time varies depending on whether the file was last modified in the last 6 months or not (or in the future). So you can get `Jun 14 09:18` or `Feb 4 2014` or `Jan 1 2017` if run on 2016-11-09. If a year is not given, then you can't assume the year is the current year. For instance, if you run it in January and get a `Dec 24 23:59`, that's the December of last year.

It's still possible to work it out like:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -dn -- "$file" | awk -v now="$(date +%m:%Y)" '{
  m=$6; d=$7; y=$8
  m = index("--JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNov", m) / 3
  if (y ~ /:/) {
    split(now, a, ":")
    y = a[2]
    if (m > a[1]) y--
  }
  printf "%02d/%02d/%04d\n", d, m, y
  exit}'
```

But best would be to get the time in the right format from the start. With `zsh`, you can use its `stat` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat -LF %d/%m/%Y +mtime -- $file
```

On a GNU system, you can do:

```
date -r "$file" +%d/%m/%Y
```

(though for symlinks, it gives you the modification time of the target).

or:

```
find -- "$file" -prune -printf '%Td/%Tm/%TY\n'
```

on BSDs:

```
stat -t %d/%m/%Y -f %Sm -- "$file"
```

Or using `perl` for portability:

```
perl -MPOSIX -le '@s = lstat shift or die "lstat: $!";
  print strftime "%d/%m/%Y", localtime $s[9]' -- "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ls`, you can do this:  `ls -l --time-style=+%d/%m/%Y`

Comment: That's GNU-specific though. Among GNU tools `date -r`, `find -printf` or `stat` would be more appropriate.